SSH: Convenient password management for server that does not allow SSH keys
I need to connect by SSH to a remote server that does not accept SSH keys. They only allow SSH authentication by username and password.
Is there a way to setup things such that my terminal (or shell, or something) remembers my password for this remote, so I don't have to type it every time I login?
